# call other methods if django rest framework's response code is 201 (successfully created)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I extend django views like this

```
class UserList(APIView):
    def post(self, etc, etc):
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Now I want to call other methods if the post response is a success.
How can I do it in the same class UserList? (or do you have a better idea?)

Comment: Where do you want to call other methods, in the UserList view before sending the response?

Comment: after the response is 201 (successfully created)

Comment: Does this other method includes calling a view or something or just normal methods? If not, why don't you call these other methods before the `return` statement. Actually, the flow is not quite clear.

Comment: I can't call the method before `return Response(serializer.data, status=status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)` it'll return  `HTTP/1.1" 400 6181`

Comment: this is a generic method in django which is extending the APIVIEW class

Comment: anyway, what I want is clearly stated there. I want to call a method after post is success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `PostSuccessMixin` class which will override the `dispatch()` method. Then, we will inherit this mixin in our view and call the super's `dispatch()`. On calling that, we will get the proper DRF response. Then we can check if the status code of the response was 201. If it was 201, then we call the other methods here. In the end, we return the original DRF response recieved initially after calling the super's `dispatch()`.

```
class PostSuccessMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(PostSuccessMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if response.status_code == 201:
            ...
            call other methods
            ...
        return response
```

In your views, inherit this mixin. 
**views.py**

```
class UserList(PostSuccessMixin, APIView):
    def post(self, etc, etc):
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: I cancel accepting your answer because I got an error saying `invalid port number: "None"` in the class PostSuccessMixin. The class PostSuccessMixin has a function importing other class(creating an object of a class). I think The error invalid port is because of http response from APIVIEW.

Comment: Can you post the function you are calling there? Do you define a  port on the `UserList` view or the method you are calling?

Comment: the imported class is named test and inside the test class has an object creation of dbcon. If I comment out db connection everything is passed. Does db connection interferes with APIVIEW? since we have dispatch method in PostSuccessMixin?

Comment: I don't think dispatch would be causing an error. Check if you defined the correct port number for your dbcon model database settings. Also, does the error come on the line `response = super(..`?

Comment: Yes the database connection is correct. The error wasn't about the db port. If I change the db port, db connection error will get thrown. And the serialize.save() will not save at all. Anyway, the error wasn't on the response = super(..) it was on the method inside PostSuccessMixin which creating an object of test. Test is in test.py in a diff file than views.py . Dbcon is inside test.py

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for your help sir. It was my silly mistake that got the dbcon error. WRONG FILE PATH. LOL.

Comment: Yeah it happens with me too sometimes. Great that the problem got solved! :)